# What is the derivative of the following integral?

Tags: integration, derivatives

Consider the vector $(a_M, a_S) \in R^2_{+}$. Vector components are drawn from a joint log-normal distribution $G(a_M, a_S)$ with mean $(\mu_M,\mu_S)$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma$.

Now, I have the following expression
$$N_M(W_M)=\int^{\infty}_0 \int^{a_MW_M}_0 a_M \ g(a_M, a_S) da_M da_S$$

where the second integral sign refers to the second $d$, i.e. we are integrating over all $a_S$ that are lower than the product $a_MW_M$.

And I am interested in its derivative, and Eric gave the answer below, equal to $$\int^{\infty}_0  a^2_M \ g(a_M, a_MW_M) da_M$$

Now, I am interested in the ratio between the two expression, meaning
$$\frac{\int^{\infty}_0  a^2_M \ g(a_M, a_MW_M) da_M}{\int^{\infty}_0 \int^{a_MW_M}_0 a_M \ g(a_M, a_S) da_M da_S}$$

Is there a way to simplify it?

Comment: As you've written it, it makes no sense, but the notation is so cumbersome it's difficult to decipher. You are writing $\int_0^{wx} g(x,y)dx$. This is nonsense. Also, since $N_M$ is a function of the single variable $W_M$, you should not write partial derivative.

Comment: the notation is confusing, it is $da_M da_S$ the Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}^2$? And what means $a_MW_M$, it is a product?

Comment: @TedShifrin Conventions vary, and some people (not me!) tie the 2nd integral sign to the second $d$ in which case it's OK.

Comment: @ancientmathematician All I can say is AGH. I've seen that some physicists write the $dx\,dy$ before the integrand, but never reversal of variables.

Comment: @TedShifrin I apologize. The 2nd integral sign refers to the second d here. We are integrating over all a_S that are lower than the product a_MW_M

Comment: OK, so you switch the order of integration and then it's just the usual fundamental theorem of calculus. There are details to worry about. But probably not where you sit. Eric gave a more technically complete answer :)

Comment: @TedShifrin thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming "$\mathrm{d}a_M \,\mathrm{d}a_S$" is intended as a [product measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_measure) so that the intended computation using [iterated integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_integral) ordering of the measure factors (so that the upper bound on the second integral is the dummy variable bound in the first integral instead of a different free variable) is
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}W_M} \int_0^\infty \; \int_0^{a_M \cdot W_M} \; a_M g(a_M, a_S) \,\mathrm{d}a_S \,\mathrm{d}a_M  \text{,}  $$and assuming the undefined function, $g$, is sufficiently well behaved that the order of integration can be reversed (for example, the hypotheses of the [Fubini-Tonelli theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Fubini%E2%80%93Tonelli_theorem), of [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem), or of [other theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_integration_(calculus)#Basic_theorems) are satisfied), we apply the (first half of the) [fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus) with the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) to obtain
$$  {} = \int_0^\infty a_M^2 g(a_M, a_M W_M) \,\mathrm{d}a_M  \text{.}  $$

Of course, the weird notation may not be what I guessed above, so, to get responsive answers,  you may need to augment your Question with the definition of the notation you used.